# Direct limit of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space.

Suppose $X_n$ are subspaces of X with $X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \cdots \subset X$.

I want to prove that $\varinjlim X_n =\cup_n X_n$.

I have some trouble in proving that $\cup_n X_n$ satisfies the universal property of direct limits.

More precisely, I have a difficulty to prove the map $\Phi : \cup_n X_n \longrightarrow Y$ by $x \longrightarrow j_n(x)$ if $x\in X_n$ is continuous, where $Y$ is any topological space with continuous maps $j_n :X_n \longrightarrow Y $.

Comment: The trouble is justified. The subspace topology of the union doesn't have to carry the colimit topology (that's also the reason for the definition concerning the topology of CW-complexes).

Comment: to Mr. Vaidyanathan, I'm not able to prove $\Phi^{-1}(E)=\cup j_n^{-1}(E)$ is open in $\cup X_n$ for an open set $E$ of $Y$.

Comment: The result seems true if we require $X_n$ are open subspaces addtionaly?!
With the additional condition, proving the continuity of $\Phi$ becomes easier.

Comment: Yes it is true when the $X_n$ are open subspaces of $X$.

Answer (score 20):

Take $X=\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology and $X_i = \{1,\dotsc,i\}$. Then each $X_i$ carries the discrete topology, and it follows easily that their colimit $\varinjlim_i X_i$ also carries the discrete topology. But the union $\cup_i X_i$, equipped with the subspace topology, actually equals $X$ and doesn't carry the discrete topology.

Comment: Maybe augment this (nicely incisive) answer by discussion of obtaining the colimit as quotient, etc?

Comment: This is not necessary. Colimits of discrete spaces are discrete by abstract nonsense (the functor $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Top}$ which equips a set with the discrete topology is left adjoint to the forgetful functor, hence preserves colimits).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant simply the more-general riff about making colimits of not-necessarily-discrete topological spaces. But maybe it doesn't matter for the question at hand.