# Direct limit and its result

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the book of Rotman's An Introduction To Algebraic Topology, I was found some theorem about direct limit (page $71$):
$\textbf{Corollary 4.17}$: If $X$ is a space for which there exists an integer $0\leq n$ with
$H_n(A) = 0$ for every compact subspace of X, then $H_n(X) =0$.
$\textbf{Theorem 4.18}$: Let $X =\cup_{p=1}^{\inf} X^P$ with $X^P \subset X^{p+l}$ for all $p$ (call the inclusion maps $i_p$ from $X^P$ to $X$ and $k_p$ from $X^P$ to $X^{P+1}$). If every compact subspace $A$ of $X$ is contained in some $X^P$, then $cls\,a \in H_n(X)$ is zero if and only if there exist $p$ and
$cls\, a' \in H_n(X)$ with 
$$i_{p*}\,(cls\, a')=cls \, a \,\,\,\, and\,\,\, k_{p*}(cls \, a')=0$$

Why Theorem $4.18$ and Corollary $4.17$ are instances of a more general result: functor $H_n$ preserves $\textbf{direct limits}$ over a directed index set ?
I study about $\textbf{direct limits}$ in spanier's book but can't answer to above qoestion!

Can somebody halp me or give me some refrenses ?

Comment: I really don't see how 4.17 follows from $H_n$ preserving direct limits. After all a space is not necessarly a direct limit of its compact subspaces. Counterexample given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611707/direct-limit-of-topoloical-spaces

Comment: @freakish, OK,Could u please tell me about the 4.18?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1745431/116766)? I think the point (for Cor. 4.17) is that if you have a homology class $\sigma \in H_n(X)$, then it corresponds to a singular chain that has image in a compact subset $A$. But this chain must be the boundary of a larger dimensional chain by triviality of homology of $A$, hence $\sigma =0$. Thm. 4.18 is similar.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama: I know this proof. Actually i'm trying to find some proof  by notion of direct limit.

Comment: @A-M [[Spanier](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9322-1), p. 175] has a short description of such a proof. There is an isomorphism $$\varinjlim_\alpha\Delta(X_\alpha) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} \Delta(X)$$ given by the universal property of the direct limit. You can check that this is an isomorphism using a similar argument to my previous comment. Then, [[Spanier](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9322-1), Thm. 4.1.7] implies $$\varinjlim_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} H_n(X).$$